# Rx Kotlin/Java Observable on state

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

Is any way to create an RxJava2 `Observable` to notify state changes? like:

```
private var internalState = "state1"
val state: Observable<String> = Observable(...)
...
fun updateState(newState: String) { ... } // !!! attention: I need to notify all subscribers about this new state
```

then use it every where like:

```
// observe on state
state.subscribe(...)
```

this subscription must be called every state updates

Comment: note: I can use `Observable.defer` or `Observable.fromCallback` to create `Observable` but I need a way to re-notify all subscribers about data change, without new subscribe need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research:

```
val source = PublishSubject.create<String>()

var state = "state1"
    get() = field // redundant: only to show it's possible to get state directly: maybe for class internal usages
    set(value) {
        field = value
        source.onNext(field)
    }
```

Now use normal `subscribe`s or create new `Observable` from `source`

```
source.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Also check `BehaviorSubject<T>` <- this one return last known state on subscribe.